# Cannot upvote comments on topic requests in documentation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation

I looked at the topic and tried upvoting the comment but found that there is no upvote button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't ever recall a time in which comments were upvotable in Documentation.  This doesn't seem to be a bug, it's just that comments on topic requests don't enjoy the same level of status or prestige that comments in Q&A do.

Answer (score 0):

As [Makoto mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349628/1438), we haven't had voting on Documentation comment and aren't planning on it. It's certainly something we could add if needed, but so far there's not a lot of reason to add votes. (They were a [fairly late feature on Q&A too](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/16/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/).)